# In Java which is an object association. faced in interview

Tags: oop

1. which one is not an object association a) simple association

   b) inheritance

   c) Aggregation

   d) Association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know what an *association* is.

And association in O.O.P *defines a relationship between classes of objects that allows one object instance to cause another to perform an action on its behalf* (Wikipedia ,2016)

Read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(object-oriented_programming)

This means that you can call objects from one class into another and allow it to "mutate" perform some logic/action on behalf of another object.

I think the answer to your question is c) Aggregation. This is because aggregation in used in Unified Modelling Language (UML). This is when one object is *Strongly Composed* of another. This means it is made-up of many objects. In this, the object isn't taking permission to call that object, it is composed of them which means that it can call them directly.

a) and d) contain the word "Association" already so that shouldn't be the answer.

b) Inheritance is when you `extend` a parent/super class into a subclass. This is when the superclass contains objects and methods which can be called by the subclass. The difference with the subclass is that it can have it's own unique parameters for the objects (which the superclass doesn't have).